# Please suggest Joomla or Drupal software product theme?

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6, joomla

I'm looking for a Joomla or Drupal software product site theme(preferably Drupal and free)? I have no problem if the theme needs some css hacking. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what do you meant by "software product site theme" ? Please elaborate

Comment: I mean I'm doing a program and I need to make a website for it.

Comment: @NoParrots, I'm making a utility program and I wanna sell it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're selling the utility program and you're using Drupal, you should use Ubercart. (check out http://ubercart.org and http://drupal.org/project/ubercart ).

A good theme optimized for selling products is http://drupal.org/project/acquia_prosper

To get up and running with acquia prosper and ubercart in general quickly I would recommend the following project http://drupal.org/project/uberdrupal

Comment: I'm looking for a theme something like winzip.